# Trying to set up VPS as a proxy servering using squid

Tags: networking, server, proxy, squid

I am completely new to Linux, just bought a VPS for a purpose of setting it as a proxy server, I am [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html.en) to do so.

I get stuck at the 3rd section where it says:

"Using Squid's access control, you may configure use of Internet services proxied by Squid to be available only users with certain Internet Protocol (IP) addresses. For example, we will illustrate access by users of the 192.168.42.0/24 subnetwork only:

Add the following to the bottom of the ACL section of your /etc/squid/squid.conf file:

```
acl fortytwo_network src 192.168.42.0/24
```

What IP do I have to put there and where do I get it from?